# Showing DISTINCT cases where NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out all of the records that only have the value null in two columns. The problem I am running into is that

I have 565 ROWS with Columns including ID, Allegation1, allegation 2, date, concatenatedalleg12
so it shows up as

```
ID    ALLEG1    ALLEG2    DATE    CONCATENATED
1     NULL      NULL      DATE1   NULL
1     NULL      A1        DATE1   A1
1     A2        NULL      DATE1   A2
2     NULL      NULL      DATE2   NULL
2     NULL      B1        DATE2   B2
3     NULL      NULL      DATE3   NULL
4     NULL      NULL      DATE4   NULL
5     NULL      NULL      DATE5   NULL
5     NULL      C1        DATE5   C1
```

I want to show only:

```
ID    ALLEG1    ALLEG2    DATE    CONCATENATED
3     NULL      NULL      DATE3   NULL
4     NULL      NULL      DATE4   NULL
```

How do I get only the distinct cases where there is only one row of nulls without including the 1 2 and 5 null rows that also have nonnull 2+ rows.

Comment: Just to be specific: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Server Management Studio @barranka

Comment: oh I see ... you want the ones where there is only one row with nulls?

Comment: Just to be specific: SQL Server *is* the RDBMS... the "Management studio" is a front-end for SQL Server

Comment: Sorry yes, SQL SERVER, and also @hogan, yes only one row with nulls with no other rows. If ID has a NULL ROW but also has a second or more row, how do you only count one with one row of null.

Comment: @epv Did any of the solutions work for you? If so, please mark the one that worked as your answer.

Comment: FYI: I deleted my answer and comments because it's getting far beyond merely answering your question, and while I (like most) am here to help, that becomes very difficult when it's so hard to tell what it is you need to know.

Comment: @hvd, I was getting really close to getting the results I wanted with your code except that I am learning so, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
    ID,
    MAX(ALLEG1) AS ALLEG1,
    MAX(ALLEG2) AS ALLEG2,
    MAX([DATE]) AS [DATE],
    MAX(CONCATENATED) AS CONCATENATED
 FROM 
    @TBL
 GROUP BY 
    ID
 HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN ALLEG1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN ALLEG2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: A much simpler `having` clause is just:  `having max(alleg1) is null and max(alleg2) is null`.

Comment: Yes. But with the formula a more complex conditional formula can be easily created such as case when ALLEG2 in ('val1','val2') then 0 else 1 end providing some extra versatility in the solution criteria.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH idswithonerow AS
(
   SELECT ID FROM
   (
      SELECT ID, 
             COUNT() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS CN
      FROM tablename   
   ) as tmp 
   WHERE CN = 1
)
  select ID, ALLEG1, ALLEG2, DATE, CONCATINATED
  FROM tablename
  WHERE ALLEG11 is null and ALLEG2 is null
  AND ID IN SELECT ID FROM idswithonerow
```

Comment: @Hogan, I GET THESE ERRORS: Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
The COUNT function requires 1 argument(s).
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: @hvd, trying your method says: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The column 'INCNUM' was specified multiple times for 'sub'.

Comment: @epv - Try `COUNT(ALLEG1)`.  What you count depends on your business rules.

Comment: @HVD, i did change the table names in the query and yes I am joining. Also, If I remove the     *, then what do I replace it with because once I add ID my conditions on the bottom WHERE become an error.

Comment: @hogan, now i get Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: @hvd, I used the last comment where I put select* from (select posts.ud, posts.userid, users.name from posts left outer join users on users.userid = posts.userid) as sub, and it works but returns nothing.

Comment: @hpv, yes, these tabls aren't actually test tables but infact do have data in it. My join statements has been used in other queries that have returned data.

Comment: @epv - hmm... which version of SQL Server are you using?  Is it > 2005?

Comment: @hogan, it is. I beleive another code below has worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you only need to show the `NULL` place-holders, you could do something like this:

```
select ID
     , null as ALLEG1
     , null as ALLEG2
     , DATE
     , null as CONCATENATED
from yourTable
where ALLEG1 is null and ALLEG2 is null
group by ID, DATE;
```

of course, if you can simply ignore those columns, things become simpler:

```
select ID
     , DATE
from yourTable
where ALLEG1 is null and ALLEG2 is null
group by ID, DATE;
```

Then you can deal with those required columns in your front-end

Comment: This will give the wrong results. When you do a max, say for ID 1, it will pick Alleg2 as 1 (as 2nd row in the dataset has a value).

Comment: @rvphx edited, thanks (I was thinking on something and writing something else... duh, damn potato chips, they mess up with my brain)

Answer (score 0):

Try use this query

```
select *
from xxx
where ((ALLEG1 is not  null) and (ALLEG2 is null) and (DATE is null) and (CONCATENATED is null))
or
((ALLEG1 is  null) and (ALLEG2 is not null) and (DATE is  null) and (CONCATENATED is  null))
or
((ALLEG1 is  null) and (ALLEG2 is  null) and (DATE is not null) and (CONCATENATED is  null))
or
((ALLEG1 is  null) and (ALLEG2 is  null) and (DATE is  null) and (CONCATENATED is not null))


having count(id)=1
```